Why there are multiple JQuery executions on Main thread on chrome lighthouse report
I recently did a page load test on one of my websites using the Chrome Lighthouse tool.
As for the report 33.9s are consumed for main thread work. After digging deeper I have found that multiple JQuery scripts are executing.


Then I checked the codebase and only one instance that JQuery is referenced. The why there are multiple scripts showing in chrome dev tools?

Those are multiple slow tasks being run by the same instance of jQuery..?

@AKX Hmm. Good thought. Any clue on how to dig deeper on this?

Your browser's profiler. You should be able to see those long invocations, and fix them.
